# iOS UIButton event when its frame at negative position from superview

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a view A has frame (100, 200, 320, 200). I add a UIButton B to view A with frame (0, **-100**, 50, 50). How can I receive TouchUpInside event of button B.

I tried some ways on Internet

A.clipsToBound = NO;

on view A I implemented hitTest:withEvent to return a received view is B.

But when I touch on button B, it NOT go on function hitTest and so it do nothing.

Why can I do it? I read on Apple document about UIView, it said that set clipsToBound is NO, problem solved, but I don't think so. Is problem about my negative position y of my button B (-100).

Comment: Yes the problem is with origin.y of the button B. If it is negative then it is out of the view A. Where exactly you want to put button in view A?

Comment: @Akash It's all for my app design and I have to put to it. You imagine that view A is a part of my main view and view B is a small part of view A. I can NOT add view B to my main view. is there any good solution to solve it. Thanks

Comment: I think you want to add button to your main view. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

B isn't on the view. it's 100 points above it. How is a user supposed to interact with it?

Comment: Yes, it's actual my problem. Can you have any idea or suggestion, Thanks

Comment: Use a frame that appears on screen.

Comment: @Abizem Can you describe more clearly, what you mean a frame? Thanks :)

Comment: The frame is the rectangle that a view occupies in its superview. As you've said in your question the frame of B is outside of A.

Comment: Yes, How can I use it while I can get event touch. :)

Comment: If you can't see your button, you have to do it programatically - but I don't think this is what your question is about. Why can't you put the button on A so that it is visible?